# Sort in lucene by the start

Tags: sorting, lucene

I try to sort a Lucene search, but I can not find the better way to sort the results.
I want first the result which start with my expression and the secondary order is alphabetical.

There are any way to sort in Lucene by the start?

I tried with a Custom Collector but I am not sure if it is the right way.

Thanks.

Comment: /what's your expression? could you give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorting in Lucene is usually a bad practice, and if you're sorting on the fields you were searching for (and with the precise expression you were searching for) - Lucene is supposed to sort your results for you using its scoring algorithm.

Now, if we put that aside, when you have opened your **IndexSearcher** and are about to use the **search()** you can use this method : **search(Query query, int n, Sort sort)** and implement a Sort class to define what your sorting strategy is.

[More documentation here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#search(org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int,%20org.apache.lucene.search.Sort))

Regards,

Comment: Thanks, I order with a Sort:

Comment: no pb, don't forget to mark the question as resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I order with a Sort:
new Sort(new SortField(fieldToSort, SortField.Type.STRING,false));

And then with a Collections.sort the result given from Lucene.

```
Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<View>(){
            public int compare(View v1, View v2){
                if(v1.startsWith(text)) {
                    if(v2.startsWith(text)){
     return  v1.compareTo(v2);
                    }  else {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }else if(v2.startsWith(text)){
                    return 1;
                }
                return  v2.compareTo(v1);
            }
        });
```

Thanks a lot.